# File upload in Java from Java client using HTTP

Tags: java, file-upload

My client code is in java. It uploads file to different server based on request. These request go between countries like "India to US", "US to UK" etc. Also, sometimes files are as large as 2 GB. My current code is ineffective as it is slow in uploading file and requires you to give 1 GB heap space even to upload just 60 MB file.

```
    String lineEnd = "\r\n";
    String twoHyphens = "--";
    String boundary = "*****";
    int bytesRead, bytesAvailable, bufferSize;
    byte[] buffer;
    int maxBufferSize = 1 * 1024 * 1024;
    //System.out.println("Uploading the file");
    String responseFromServer = "";       
    String urlString = "http://stcss.us.com:8888/codesign/UploadServlet";       


    try {
        //------------------ CLIENT REQUEST
        FileInputStream fileInputStream = 
            new FileInputStream(new File(exsistingFileName));
        int file_size = fileInputStream.available();

        if (file_size > 1000 * 1024 * 1024) {
            System.out.println("File Size  Error\n Max Size allowed is 500MB");
            System.exit(1);
        }

        // open a URL connection to the Jsp
        URL url = new URL(urlString);
        // Open a HTTP connection to the URL
        conn = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
        // Allow Inputs
        conn.setDoInput(true);

        // Allow Outputs
        conn.setDoOutput(true);
        // Don't use a cached copy.
        conn.setUseCaches(false);
        // Use a post method.
        conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", 
                                "multipart/form-data;boundary=" + 
                                boundary);
    //conn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/octet-stream");
    conn.setRequestProperty("password", password);
        conn.setRequestProperty("signingParameters", signingParameters);
        dos = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());
        dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
        dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"upload\";" + 
                       " filename=\"" + exsistingFileName + "\"" + 
                       lineEnd);
        dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
        // create a buffer of maximum size
        bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
        bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
        buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
        // read file and write it into form...
        bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
        while (bytesRead > 0) {
            //   System.out.println ("file size is"+file_size+"avaiable is"+bytesAvailable);
            dos.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
            bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
            bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
            bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
        }

        // send multipart form data necesssary after file data...
        dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
        dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);
        // close streams
        fileInputStream.close();
        dos.flush();
        dos.close();
    } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {
        System.out.println("From CLIENT CLIENT REQUEST Malformed:" + ex);
        System.exit(0);
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        System.out.println("From CLIENT CLIENT REQUEST:" + ioe);
        System.exit(0);
    }
```

What are the ways I can change this code to make upload faster and also get rid of heap space for considerably smaller file? Is something neeeded to be changed on server side? I am using apache-commons-fileupload on the server side.

Comment: Why don't You use something like Http Components, so You dont have to do what others have done before? ;)

Comment: I heard that java.nio provide faster uploads. Is it true? How to use that?